# schema export unsuccessful

Tags: mysql, hibernate, connectivity

I am working with Java, Hibernate and MySql Database. I want to create the tables and do their mapping using hibernate, but I am getting the following error of connectivity:-

15:46:27,691 ERROR [main] SchemaExport:274 - schema export unsuccessful
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a database connection problem. I could be a misconfiguration.